# Prestashop 8 API add product, Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: prestashop

I am getting error while adding a product via API webservice and i don't know what is missing :
This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 500. That means: Internal Server Error - (Code 3): [PHP Warning #2] Trying to access array offset on value of type null (...\prestashop\classes\Product.php, line 7094).

```
$url = 'http:///localhost/prestashop/';
$key = 'ST5TVKFHV685W4MWN9BYF2HXG3PB19FB';
$debug = true;
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, $key, $debug);

$blankXml = $webService->get(['url' => $url . 'api/products?schema=blank']);

$productXML = $blankXml->product->children();

$productXML->price = 100;
$productXML->id_category_default = 3; // 3 is an id of an existing parent category
$productXML->position_in_category = 1;

$createdXml = $webService->add([
            'resource' => 'products',
            'postXml' => $blankXml->asXML(),
        ]);
```

```
Here is the request debug : 
HTTP REQUEST HEADER
GET /presta/api/products?schema=blank HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Authorization: Basic U1Q1VFZLRkhWNjg1VzRNV045QllGMkhYRzNQQjE5RkI6
Accept: */*

HTTP RESPONSE HEADER
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 May 2023 10:47:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) PHP/8.0.26 mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
X-Powered-By: PrestaShop Webservice
Access-Time: 1684234037
PSWS-Version: 8.0.4
Execution-Time: 0.033
Content-Sha1: 217deb94edcdf5ec414f5abb7f30aed375ccedb4
Content-Length: 4543
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
RETURN HTTP BODY
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<product>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    <id_manufacturer><![CDATA[]]></id_manufacturer>
    <id_supplier><![CDATA[]]></id_supplier>
    <id_category_default><![CDATA[]]></id_category_default>
    <new><![CDATA[]]></new>
    <cache_default_attribute><![CDATA[]]></cache_default_attribute>
    <id_default_image><![CDATA[]]></id_default_image>
    <id_default_combination><![CDATA[]]></id_default_combination>
    <id_tax_rules_group><![CDATA[]]></id_tax_rules_group>
    <position_in_category><![CDATA[]]></position_in_category>
    <type><![CDATA[]]></type>
    <id_shop_default><![CDATA[]]></id_shop_default>
    <reference><![CDATA[]]></reference>
    <supplier_reference><![CDATA[]]></supplier_reference>
    <location><![CDATA[]]></location>
    <width><![CDATA[]]></width>
    <height><![CDATA[]]></height>
    <depth><![CDATA[]]></depth>
    <weight><![CDATA[]]></weight>
    <quantity_discount><![CDATA[]]></quantity_discount>
    <ean13><![CDATA[]]></ean13>
    <isbn><![CDATA[]]></isbn>
    <upc><![CDATA[]]></upc>
    <mpn><![CDATA[]]></mpn>
    <cache_is_pack><![CDATA[]]></cache_is_pack>
    <cache_has_attachments><![CDATA[]]></cache_has_attachments>
    <is_virtual><![CDATA[]]></is_virtual>
    <state><![CDATA[]]></state>
    <additional_delivery_times><![CDATA[]]></additional_delivery_times>
    <delivery_in_stock><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></delivery_in_stock>
    <delivery_out_stock><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></delivery_out_stock>
    <product_type><![CDATA[]]></product_type>
    <on_sale><![CDATA[]]></on_sale>
    <online_only><![CDATA[]]></online_only>
    <ecotax><![CDATA[]]></ecotax>
    <minimal_quantity><![CDATA[]]></minimal_quantity>
    <low_stock_threshold><![CDATA[]]></low_stock_threshold>
    <low_stock_alert><![CDATA[]]></low_stock_alert>
    <price><![CDATA[]]></price>
    <wholesale_price><![CDATA[]]></wholesale_price>
    <unity><![CDATA[]]></unity>
    <unit_price><![CDATA[]]></unit_price>
    <unit_price_ratio><![CDATA[]]></unit_price_ratio>
    <additional_shipping_cost><![CDATA[]]></additional_shipping_cost>
    <customizable><![CDATA[]]></customizable>
    <text_fields><![CDATA[]]></text_fields>
    <uploadable_files><![CDATA[]]></uploadable_files>
    <active><![CDATA[]]></active>
    <redirect_type><![CDATA[]]></redirect_type>
    <id_type_redirected><![CDATA[]]></id_type_redirected>
    <available_for_order><![CDATA[]]></available_for_order>
    <available_date><![CDATA[]]></available_date>
    <show_condition><![CDATA[]]></show_condition>
    <condition><![CDATA[]]></condition>
    <show_price><![CDATA[]]></show_price>
    <indexed><![CDATA[]]></indexed>
    <visibility><![CDATA[]]></visibility>
    <advanced_stock_management><![CDATA[]]></advanced_stock_management>
    <date_add><![CDATA[]]></date_add>
    <date_upd><![CDATA[]]></date_upd>
    <pack_stock_type><![CDATA[]]></pack_stock_type>
    <meta_description><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></meta_description>
    <meta_keywords><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></meta_keywords>
    <meta_title><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></meta_title>
    <link_rewrite><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></link_rewrite>
    <name><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></name>
    <description><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></description>
    <description_short><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></description_short>
    <available_now><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></available_now>
    <available_later><language id="1"><![CDATA[]]></language></available_later>
<associations>
<categories>
    <category>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    </category>
</categories>
<images>
    <image>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    </image>
</images>
<combinations>
    <combination>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    </combination>
</combinations>
<product_option_values>
    <product_option_value>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    </product_option_value>
</product_option_values>
<product_features>
    <product_feature>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    <id_feature_value><![CDATA[]]></id_feature_value>
    </product_feature>
</product_features>
<tags>
    <tag>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    </tag>
</tags>
<stock_availables>
    <stock_available>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    <id_product_attribute><![CDATA[]]></id_product_attribute>
    </stock_available>
</stock_availables>
<attachments>
    <attachment>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    </attachment>
</attachments>
<accessories>
    <product>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    </product>
</accessories>
<product_bundle>
    <product>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    <id_product_attribute><![CDATA[]]></id_product_attribute>
    <quantity><![CDATA[]]></quantity>
    </product>
</product_bundle>
</associations>
</product>
</prestashop>
HTTP REQUEST HEADER
POST /presta//api/products HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Authorization: Basic U1Q1VFZLRkhWNjg1VzRNV045QllGMkhYRzNQQjE5RkI6
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 3545
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

HTTP RESPONSE HEADER
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 16 May 2023 10:47:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) PHP/8.0.26 mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
X-Powered-By: PrestaShop Webservice
Access-Time: 1684234038
PSWS-Version: 8.0.4
Execution-Time: 0.051
Set-Cookie: PrestaShop-5a0b55fcb2919ae6e4dff6050d95afb0=def5020004a5be0a6ceb8d376f8e41b5060025ee5e056c66790d7de3f8ae25a344f82ee056f95394dc74c4aaeaeaa5704858c155d7b47f5f57d2ee2942ba638565a29621c1289640933fb866bdec294ba92720c2212a523b752717d809a6383d8e91f39355259e67e774c7eda75143e3cf42f973b7a5158bac55dc201d752348accdb5a5a1148761e79966798bea82eb95fb812e01df68ab3b585938eff2f640a0bc533d16b74c0f8ac62303cbfedc626f146ab22fe27929bf0b6cf7112eed25c122987f2a655f346d75321aaf7abb1c75b3e73e81fe102423; expires=Mon, 05-Jun-2023 10:47:17 GMT; Max-Age=1727999; path=/presta/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Content-Length: 326
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
XML SENT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<product>
    <id></id>
    <id_manufacturer></id_manufacturer>
    <id_supplier></id_supplier>
    <id_category_default>3</id_category_default>
    <new></new>
    <cache_default_attribute></cache_default_attribute>
    <id_default_image></id_default_image>
    <id_default_combination></id_default_combination>
    <id_tax_rules_group></id_tax_rules_group>
    <position_in_category>1</position_in_category>
    <type></type>
    <id_shop_default></id_shop_default>
    <reference></reference>
    <supplier_reference></supplier_reference>
    <location></location>
    <width></width>
    <height></height>
    <depth></depth>
    <weight></weight>
    <quantity_discount></quantity_discount>
    <ean13></ean13>
    <isbn></isbn>
    <upc></upc>
    <mpn></mpn>
    <cache_is_pack></cache_is_pack>
    <cache_has_attachments></cache_has_attachments>
    <is_virtual></is_virtual>
    <state></state>
    <additional_delivery_times></additional_delivery_times>
    <delivery_in_stock><language id="1"></language></delivery_in_stock>
    <delivery_out_stock><language id="1"></language></delivery_out_stock>
    <product_type>standard</product_type>
    <on_sale></on_sale>
    <online_only></online_only>
    <ecotax></ecotax>
    <minimal_quantity></minimal_quantity>
    <low_stock_threshold></low_stock_threshold>
    <low_stock_alert></low_stock_alert>
    <price></price>
    <wholesale_price></wholesale_price>
    <unity></unity>
    <unit_price></unit_price>
    <unit_price_ratio></unit_price_ratio>
    <additional_shipping_cost></additional_shipping_cost>
    <customizable></customizable>
    <text_fields></text_fields>
    <uploadable_files></uploadable_files>
    <active></active>
    <redirect_type></redirect_type>
    <id_type_redirected></id_type_redirected>
    <available_for_order></available_for_order>
    <available_date></available_date>
    <show_condition></show_condition>
    <condition></condition>
    <show_price></show_price>
    <indexed></indexed>
    <visibility></visibility>
    <advanced_stock_management></advanced_stock_management>
    <date_add></date_add>
    <date_upd></date_upd>
    <pack_stock_type></pack_stock_type>
    <meta_description><language id="1"></language></meta_description>
    <meta_keywords><language id="1"></language></meta_keywords>
    <meta_title><language id="1"></language></meta_title>
    <link_rewrite><language id="1"></language></link_rewrite>
    <name><language id="1"></language></name>
    <description><language id="1"></language></description>
    <description_short><language id="1"></language></description_short>
    <available_now><language id="1"></language></available_now>
    <available_later><language id="1"></language></available_later>
<associations>
<categories>
    <category>
    <id></id>
    </category>
</categories>
<images>
    <image>
    <id></id>
    </image>
</images>
<combinations>
    <combination>
    <id></id>
    </combination>
</combinations>
<product_option_values>
    <product_option_value>
    <id></id>
    </product_option_value>
</product_option_values>
<product_features>
    <product_feature>
    <id></id>
    <id_feature_value></id_feature_value>
    </product_feature>
</product_features>
<tags>
    <tag>
    <id></id>
    </tag>
</tags>
<stock_availables>
    <stock_available>
    <id></id>
    <id_product_attribute></id_product_attribute>
    </stock_available>
</stock_availables>
<attachments>
    <attachment>
    <id></id>
    </attachment>
</attachments>
<accessories>
    <product>
    <id></id>
    </product>
</accessories>
<product_bundle>
    <product>
    <id></id>
    <id_product_attribute></id_product_attribute>
    <quantity></quantity>
    </product>
</product_bundle>
</associations>
</product>
</prestashop>
RETURN HTTP BODY
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<errors>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[3]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[PHP Warning #2] Trying to access array offset on value of type null (C:\wamp64\www\presta\classes\Product.php, line 7094)]]></message>
</error>
</errors>
</prestashop>
```

Thank you!

i tried to add a product without category id, it's doesnt work
i triend to add values to other product attribut like state, description ....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the only solution I found is to change

```
$value = $value['id_product'];
```

to

```
$value = (isset($value['id_product']) ? $value['id_product'] : null);
```

in the Product class around the line mentioned in the error